# Top margin for DIV is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a css where I defined a class for the top div with these properties

```
.topbluebar { 
 margin:0;    
height:19px;  
width:100%;  
background-image:url('../../Images/top_blue.gif');  
clear:both;  
}
```

Here is the simple Html page

```
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <div class="topbluebar"></div>  
<div>Foo foo</div>
```

Image is appearing but not with the top of browser but with little margin from top which I don't want. 
In simple words I want to implement it like Stackexchnage `topbar` class but it doesn't seems to work for me at all.

I have read many answers but none of them worked for me yet.

[image]

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Are you saying there white space on the top, left, and right side of your image?

Comment: @CodeChaser added the SS.

Comment: @MrNeo I think this is the share link of Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kL6o3gvd/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link @avirk. I posted an answer below. Let me know if you need more assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following in your stylesheet.

```
body { margin:0;padding:0 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z18Lpy99/

Also, to avoid these kind of issues, it is a good idea to use CSS Resets. Try reading up on http://cssreset.com/

Comment: This got worked man, thanks a lot. Little trick and done. Thanks Bhai.

Answer (score 3):

A really simple solution would be to add the following css (below) to the top of your file. This essentially resets the margins to 0.

> Here is a link to the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r58hvuzp/

```
*{
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Basically lots of things in html has default styles which include default values for padding and margins.